# Fixing Install4j warnings related to external references to JRE bundles

Tags: install4j

I'm working with an Install4j v4.2.8 project file that initially referenced internal JREs in C:\Program Files\install4j\jre. It now references the same JRE bundles outside of the Install4j installation directory. Since the change was made, we've been seeing message like the following each time a JRE bundle is added to an installer:

`[WARNING] The version of the bundled JRE is too low. It should be at least 1.6!`

Is there any way to let Install4j know that those JRE bundles do indeed include 1.6 JREs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version is inferred from the file name. The format is

```
[os]-[arch]-[version][suffix].tar.gz
```

For example

```
windows-amd64-1.6.0_29.tar.gz
```

Comment: Is there a way to change the expected name format?  The files I'm referencing have names of the form jre-[version]-[os]-[arch].tar.gz, such as jre-1_6_0_30-windows-i586.tar.gz

Comment: Then you get the warning you saw. The only way not to get the warning is to use the name format above.

Comment: OK. I'll ask the relevant people if they care more about getting rid of the warnings or using the other naming format.